# Management of Task.Run and stop/cancel of method and get progress

Tags: c#, task

I have an application which currently runs Tasks on a time interval, however I would like more control over that, to be able to stop a running task and restart it by clicking a UI.

There are 6 tasks at the moment, but I would want to keep things generic, to be able to easily more when required.  I was hoping to be able to create a wrapper to control them, which I can pass a method into as a parameter.

As such I created an object, which I create as many of as there are tasks, I can get status updates from it as well as manage it

I want to:
 - Start a method/Task
 - Stop a method/Task
 - Restart a method/Task
 - Get feedback from it's log/updates/progress/errors that I record to updates List

Is this a good way to do this, is there a better way to achieve what I'm after?

```
public class ManagedTask
    {
        public ManagedTask()
        {
            CreateNewToken();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DescriptiveName { get; set; }
        public Action<CancellationToken> TheVoidToRun { private get; set; }
        private CancellationTokenSource CTokenSource { get; set; }
        private CancellationToken CToken { get; set; }
        private Task TheRunningThing { get; set; }

        public void StartIt()
        {
            if (TheRunningThing == null || TheTaskStatus() == TaskStatus.Canceled || TheTaskStatus() == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                CreateNewToken();
            }
            // Start up the Task
            AddUpdate($"Starting Task at {DateTime.Now}");
            TheRunningThing = Task.Run(() => TheVoidToRun?.Invoke(CToken), CToken);
            AddUpdate($"Started Task at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
        public void EndIt()
        {
            AddUpdate($"Cancelling Task at {DateTime.Now}");
            CTokenSource.Cancel();
            // Do - If in progress try to stop (Cancellation Token)
            // Do - Stop future repeats
        }

        private void CreateNewToken()
        {
            CTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            CToken = CTokenSource.Token;
        }

        public TaskStatus TheTaskStatus() => TheRunningThing.Status;


        internal List<string> Updates { get; set; }

        private void AddUpdate(string updates)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

So I have various methods which I'd like to pass into this such like:

```
public class AvailableTasks
{
    public async void DoStuffThatIsCancelable(CancellationToken token)
    {
        DoTheLongStuffOnRepeat(token);
    }
    public async void DoAnotherThingThatIsCancelable(CancellationToken token)
    {
        DoTheLongStuffOnRepeat(token);
    }

    private async void DoTheLongStuffOnRepeat(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Do stuff
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(500, token);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled");
                    continue;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Task Loop at {(i + 1) * 500}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I was thinking of calling it.

```
    private static readonly List<ManagedTask> _managedTasks = new List<ManagedTask>();

    public static void SetupManagedTasks()
    {
        var at = new AvailableTasks();
        var mt1 = new ManagedTask
        {
            Id = 1,
            DescriptiveName = "The cancelable task",
            TheVoidToRun = at.DoStuffThatIsCancelable,
        };
        _managedTasks.Add(mt1);

        var mt2 = new ManagedTask
        {
            Id = 2,
            DescriptiveName = "Another cancelable task",
            TheVoidToRun = at.DoAnotherThingThatIsCancelable,
        };
        _managedTasks.Add(mt2);

        mt1.StartIt();
        mt2.StartIt();

        Console.WriteLine($"{mt1.DescriptiveName} status: {mt1.TheTaskStatus()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{mt2.DescriptiveName} status: {mt2.TheTaskStatus()}");
    }

    public static void CancelTask(int id)
    {
        var mt = _managedTasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

        if (mt != null)
        {
            mt.EndIt();
            Console.WriteLine($"{mt.DescriptiveName} status: {mt.TheTaskStatus()}");
        }
    }

    public static void GetTaskStatus(int id)
    {
        var mt = _managedTasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

        if (mt != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{mt.DescriptiveName} status: {mt.TheTaskStatus()}");
        }
    }
```

However even with all the above, I suffer from the Status only ever showing RanToCompletion.

How can I structure the above to achieve what I want?

Thanks,
David

Comment: It might be enough to rethrow the `TaskCanceledException` instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suffer from the Status only ever showing RanToCompletion.

This is because your methods are using `async void`. They should be `async Task`. As I describe in my [`async` best practices article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), you should avoid `async void`.

Other notes...

> Start a method/Task
>
> Restart a method/Task

You can start (or restart) a task *on the thread pool* by using `Task.Run`. However, if you have naturally asynchronous tasks, then you can represent them as `Func<Task>` and just invoke the `Func<Task>` to start them.

> Stop a method/Task

The only appropriate way to do this is with a `CancellationToken`, which it looks like you're using correctly.

> Get feedback from it's log/updates/progress/errors that I record to updates List

I recommend using `IProgress<T>` for any kind of progress updates.